# How to cancel free trial for my Google Cloud Platform account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

I've taken a free trial for Google Cloud Platform and would like to cancel free trial for my GCP account. Need help please.

Comment: have you tried contacting google customer support?

Answer (score 11):

Open the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) in your browser.

- Go to `IAM & Admin` -> `Manage Resources` ([link](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager)).
- Select your project.
- Click the Delete button.

Once you have no projects left, wait a few minutes and then close the Billing Account.

[Create, modify, or close your Cloud Billing account](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account)

The last step is to optionally delete your Payment account. Only do this if you are not using a Payment account with other services such as YouTube, YouTube TV, Google Pay, etc. From the following page you can delete your credit card.

[Payments & subscriptions](https://myaccount.google.com/payments-and-subscriptions)